# Why imp can not find "paste" module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, paste

I meet a strange problem:

I have installed paste successfully. And "import paste" is ok.

But i noticed imp can not find it.
"imp.find_module('paste')" always gives "ImportError: No module named paste".

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('paste')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paste
>>> import paste
```

I have tested this on three different machines (Ubuntu14.04, Windows 10, Windows XP), all have similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems that `paste` module doesnt have an `__init__.py` file

If you create it manually the problem is solved

Comment: where should you put the file?

Comment: @DjDac in the `paste` module directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have duplicated this behavior.  It seems a little odd to me.  The docs describe some slight differences in `find_module()`'s behavior, but it doesn't seem to highlight anything matching this discrepancy.  I suspect it's a bug or perhaps by design but not well documented.

The `paste` package in particular uses [a `pth` configuration file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site).  You can disable this behavior with `-S` to see its effect.

```
$ python -c 'import paste' && echo found
found

$ python -S -c 'import paste' && echo found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paste
```